# What's the meaning of the expansion coefficient of the AR model?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, autocorrelation, autoregressive, white-noise, neuroimaging

I am trying to understand the meaning of the phi parameter of the AR modeling. A bit of background: I am digging into statistical parametric mapping (SPM) and the prewhitening method, used to get rid of the temporal correlation in the data.
SPM in particular models the noise with a AR(1) model, which means that the model takes into account the correlation between samples that are 1 lag apart, right?
In the specifications of the AR(1) model, phi is set to 0.2. There is no reference for this, only in a mailing list I found that this is an empirical value that is good for fMRI.
The topic of course is also explained on wikipedia:

[image]

But despite the readings and the research what I still don't get is: what's the exact effect of this parameter on the data?
When I change it in SPM, final results change drastically (in terms of statistical significance). How to assess which phi is the right phi?

Comment: AR models use lagged values of your series as explanatory variables. If you have an AR(1) model, then $X_t=\phi X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$. In this case, $\phi$ is the amount of $X_t$ that is explained by its past value, $X_{t-1}$. Note, however, that you first have to estimate $\phi$. You cannot simply say $\phi=0.2$. That is wrong! You have to estimate it and validate your model. In order to do that you need to know a little bit of the theory and use some statistics software.

Comment: Hello Guilherme, thanks a lot for your input, I guess I do have some lack here, can you please point me at some basic reference for me to understand how to estimate it and which statistics software to use?

Comment: You could get Time Series by Hamilton, but it might be a quite long read. Or try to absorb the maximum you can from this https://youtu.be/uBeM1FUk4Ps and they look for related videos on the topic. You could use R to do this estimation, but if you want something easier to deal with you should try Eviews or stata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as much an answer to your question, but to the underlying misunderstanding:

SPM does not simply set $\phi = 0.2$, it approximates the autocorrelation of an AR(1) process by a 1st-order Taylor expansion at $\phi = 0.2$. The coefficients of the resulting variance components are estimated by SPM. For a reference, see K. Friston et al. (eds.), *Statistical Parametric Mapping*, 2007, chapter 10. The rationale is that variance components can be estimated by ReML, while proper AR estimation from residuals is difficult.

This approach has been shown to often not be sufficient (look at the publications by W. Olszowy). Newer versions of SPM implement another method, called "F.A.S.T.", which appears to overcome these limitations by adding more Taylor-expansion variance components. See Corbin N, Todd N, Friston KJ, Callaghan MF. Accurate modeling of temporal correlations in rapidly sampled fMRI time series. Hum Brain Mapp. 2018;00:1–14. [link](https://doi.org/10.1002/hbm.24218)